# How do I make my menu bar to fill the width of the screen?

Tags: html, css, menu, web

This is my school project: http://sleepybear.ml

I created the menu using `<ul>` and `<li>`

I want to make the menu's background-color to fill the width of the page

My index and styles.css: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxgmzq

My css for the menu:

```
ul.menu {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333333;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

And the menu in html:

```
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="menu"><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
        <li class="menu"><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li class="menu"><a href="#forum">FORUM</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I put the code in the question itself :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply apply `margin: 0` to `<body>` like:

```css
ul.menu {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#forum">FORUM</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```